# Creating a .bin bytes file from ascii int list on Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, binary, byte

I'm trying to convert a string / int list to a .bin bytes format final file:

```
final_data = ['3247', '5146', '6971', '-8192', '8192', '11192']
final_data2 = [int(i) for i in final_data]
arr = bytes(final_data2)
with open("data.bin", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(arr)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)

How to proceed knowing that I have negative numbers and numbers larger than 256 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for something like this:
The `to_bytes()` call transform each `int` to a binary representation.

```
final_data = ['3247', '5146', '6971', '-8192', '8192', '11192']

with open("data.bin", "wb") as fh:
    for i in final_data:
      fh.write(int(i).to_bytes(32, byteorder = 'big', signed = True))
```